# Programming enterprise Java without an IDE

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ide

In the company i work, we use maven, also eclipse.

I hate eclipse after last week, because it started not to deploy to Tomcat for every 3 deploy attempt.

So i want to ask if i learn maven deeply, can i continue to develop SOA, Spring, Java and Javascript for front end applications without eclipse?

I have the courage to manage everything what an IDE manages at least for Java development.

Comment: Give Netbeans, JBuilder and Oracle JDeveloper a try. Even if you don't like these, Notepad is always there. :)

Comment: Take a look at IntelliJ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is about the IDE you use, it's about knowing the tools, their limits and behavior. Eclipse is a monster, deploying apps on Applications Servers too, both together might be a nightmare, until you know what it can do and what it can't. There is a reason why a redeploy does not work, it's not "sometimes".

Anyways, couldn't imagine working without any IDE. Think about refactoring, looking at type hierarchy, revision merge, style checks and so on.

Some link about that: http://letstalkaboutjava.blogspot.ch/2013/05/its-worth-to-know-your-tools.html